# How to retrieve previous row value in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, bigdata

Hi i am using **Pig** to move values in **HBASE**. I am trying to execute on condition if it is success i'll Concatenate a value, if it fails i'll concatenate value of previous row.
for that i tried below code but it is not working and throwing error.

**Code**:

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pat.hl7' USING PigStorage('|');
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($0 matches '.*OBR.*' or $0  matches '.*OBX.*');
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ($0 == 'OBR' ? CONCAT('HL','OBR',(chararray)$1) : CONCAT('HL','OBR',(chararray)(data -1).$1)) AS Uid, $1 AS id, $5 AS result, $3 AS resultname;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 14, column 122>  mismatched input '.' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

I want that concatenated value to be replicated in other rows till i reach another **OBR**. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to previous rows in Pig itself, but you can write an aggregate UDF that will accept all rows and do the required. But keep in mind that you also need to specify parallelism 1 or your rows will be split in chunks

Comment: I am a beginner in pig latin. Can you please share me examples so that i can `write an aggregate UDF`.

Comment: Actually you''l need to implement simple UDF (extends EvalFunc) that will get all the data after group all. But be aware, if you'll have too much data consider generating some to key to group by it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Stitch, Over and lag to calculate the data from previous row.  Not sure about efficiency though.